Elementor popup wont open outside editor or preview
I have created a full-screen popup without any triggers or conditions set. I also created a button on one of the pages that should open that popup.
The popup opens and closes fine if I click on that button while editing the page where the button is or if I go to a preview of that page. But once it is published, clicking on the button does nothing, it just changes some minor thing in HTML and nothing else, no error, no logs anything.
I can't find any feed on something similar to this.
What could be the reason for this behavior?
